# ColorGame Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The picked and selected color should be same. Still it is always alerting incorrect. By inspecting element of the correct color I found out that the background which it is returning is `background: rgb(0, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;`. Any idea how to solve this issue.

```js
var colors=[
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]
    
var squares=document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor=colors[3];
var colorDisplay=document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
colorDisplay.textContent=pickedColor;
    
for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
  squares[i].style.background=colors[i];
  squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    var clickedColor=this.style.background;
    //alert(this.style.background);
    if(clickedColor===pickedColor){
      alert("Correct");
    } else {
      alert("Incorrect");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.square {
  width: 30%;
  background: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}
    
#container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide more details and explanation? maybe use the SO provided snippets for html/js, or include a jsfiddle. Nobody can read your mind, of what the desired result should be, nor what your whole structure looks like. Thanks!

Comment: One step is to check `backgroundColor`, not the shorthand `background` property.

Comment: Maybe try `var clickedColor=this.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: First, fix your `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null",`

Comment: Andy G- Thanks, It worked

Comment: Also check the `backgroundColor` value in different browsers, there are likely to be different results.